# AngularFire (angular 8) storage - uploading documents

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I want to upload docs, pdfs to firebase in my angular 8 app using angularfire. Everything is set up and mostly working but it only allows uploading image and video file types. Uploading docs, pdfs, or anything else gives 'unsupported file type'. Is there a different method or workaround for this?

(a super hacky, not viable workaround I found was just renaming the doc to .png, and it uploads fine, and can be downloaded, renamed back and opened)

Comment: Can you check the storage rules, if you have written anything like only upload images?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I only have the default rule which is to require authentication

Comment: Can you please paste your rules once?

Comment: service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}